# Pine Script: delete already offset plot

Tags: pine-script

Suppose i have a variable forecast_value, which i wanna plot as a value on a "next bar" from current bar ONLY. I did something like below.
plot(barstate.islast ? forecast_value : na, style=plot.style_circles, offset = 1)

which works very well.  Say on bar T, I have the forecast value on bar T+1

However, when another bar comes (ie. bar T+1 came) , the previous forecast value (base on Bar T) is still showing on the chart at Bar T+1. while a new forecasted value( base on bar T+1) is showing on T+2. How do i only keep the latest one or deleted the old plotted forecast value please?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `plot`, you should use `line`s. You can see more details [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html).

Basically, you would call `line.new()` when your condition to draw the line is `true` and at the same time call `line.delete` to remove the old line.

Or you can have one `line` instance and just modify its coordinates by using `line.set_xy1()` and `line.set_xy2()` functions.